# Sql Server LOCK with CTE - Avoid duplicate processing

Tags: sql-server, locking, common-table-expression

I have a table with thousands of transactions and multiple instances of a service, has to process the transactions one by one. To avoid, duplicate processing, i am using a column to block the transaction by service user. I have used TABLOCK and XLOCK on SELECT, but I am using CTE to block.

To me all looks good, but wanted expert's opinion to validate the same to avoid duplicate processing. Is there any possibility that two users might block same transaction in any given time  in my logic?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyTicket] (
    @username VARCHAR(20),
    @id INT OUTPUT)
AS
;WITH result AS (
     SELECT TOP 1 id, trx_user, trx_status 
     FROM dbo.transaction_details t WITH(TABLOCK, XLOCK)
     WHERE t.trx_user IS NULL AND t.trx_status IS NULL
     ORDER BY t.id
)
UPDATE result
SET trx_user = @Username,
    trx_status = 'NEW',
    @id = id
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any possibility that two users might block same transaction in any given time in my logic?

No.  Just make sure you understand that if you run GetMyTicket in a transaction, no other session can run GetMyTicket until you commit the transaction.

You can get additional concurrency with `WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK)`, see [Using tables as queues](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), and you can serialize calls to that query with [sp_getaplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[sp_releaseapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and not hold an exclusive lock until the end of your transaction.

Comment: You'd need an index covering all the columns also, otherwise you end up with a full scan either way

Comment: @David Browne: Thanks for the details. I will look into the link too. If two clients are trying to execute the SP at same time, the other will wait until the first execution is complete. No error occurs correct? Also, what is the scope of the lock, as I locked only on SELECT, but using CTE, then how the lock scope is extended to CTE. 
`
1. SELECT TOP1 * FROM table1 (TABLOCK, XLOCK) WHERE id = 23
2. INSERT INTO table1 ('aaa', 'bbb')
`
what is the scope of the lock here, bot commands are part of same query?

Comment: @Charlieface - id in above example is identity col and a primary key. do i really need index on other cols?

Comment: @fayaz.net93 Not if it's a clustered index, because that includes all other columns (a primary key by default is clustered but it doesn't have to be)

Comment: The XLOCK will be held for the duration of the transaction.  If you don't have an explicit transaction, then the whole statement will be run in a transaction.  So lock will _at least_ be held until the INSERT is complete and committed.